# ERROR : User did not initialize spark context

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Log error :

> TestSuccessfull
>    2018-08-20 04:52:15 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13
>   2018-08-20 04:52:15 ERROR ApplicationMaster:91 - Uncaught exception: 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:800)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:799)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:824)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
>   2018-08-20 04:52:15 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Error log on console After submit command :

> 2018-08-20 05:47:35 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1534690018301_0035 (state: ACCEPTED)
>   2018-08-20 05:47:36 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1534690018301_0035 (state: ACCEPTED)
>   2018-08-20 05:47:37 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1534690018301_0035 (state: FAILED)
>   2018-08-20 05:47:37 INFO  Client:54 - 
>        client token: N/A
>        diagnostics: Application application_1534690018301_0035 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1534690018301_0035_000002 exited with  exitCode: 13
>   Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-08-20 05:47:36.454]Exception from container-launch.
>   Container id: container_1534690018301_0035_02_000001
>   Exit code: 13

My code :

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Gathering Data")            
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

submit command :

`spark-submit --class spark_basic.Test_Local --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  /home/IdeaProjects/target/Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

discription :

I have installed spark on hadoop in psedo distribustion mode.

`spark-shell` working fine. only problem when i used cluster mode .

My code also work file . i am able print output but at final its giving error .

Comment: Why are you using SparkContext? Are you not using Spark2? If so, use SparkSession

Comment: i tried using sparksession but same error no chage

Answer (score 12):

I presume your lines of code has a line which sets master to local.

```
SparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")
```

if so, try to comment out that line and try again as you will be setting the master to yarn in your command

```
/usr/cdh/current/spark-client/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.sparkApp --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 40 --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 17g --executor-memory 22g --files /usr/cdh/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml /home/user/sparkApp.jar
```

Comment: i removed everything and given print("test successful")..and still it print in log file but give failed status with same error.
looks like issue is something else

Comment: My error : 
ERROR ApplicationMaster:91 - Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!

Comment: You installed spark in psedo mode so your master cant be yarn its should look something like --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 or local[*](Basically it should point to the JVM which triggers the application) and --deploy-mode cluster. your Application manager fails 2 time due to yarn's default retry of twice. as far as exit code 13 there is no exit code 13 in YARN exit codes. Hence , I strongly believe change your master from yarn to others related to your psedo mode it should be good to go.

Comment: tried with with without local[*] and in submit with without --master yarn:
my code is only  def main(args: Array[String]){ print("test") } but still giving same error after printing "test" ...and when i try spark-shell --master yarn .its working .

Comment: 2018-08-20 23:33:55 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - Waiting for spark context initialization...
test
2018-08-20 23:33:55 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13
2018-08-20 23:33:55 ERROR ApplicationMaster:91 - Uncaught exception:

Comment: able to work in client mode but not in cluster mode dont know why

Comment: Hadoop pseudodistributed can run YARN... spark:// won't work if you don't start the standalone master server

Comment: i used /home/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master spark://mahendra-system:6066 --class spark_basic.Test_Local --deploy-mode cluster /home/SparkTraining-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   which successfully submitted to spark master but i want my job should see in  http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps/FINISHED

Comment: i able to spark submit on yarn in client deploymode why not in cluster mode

Comment: i am facing the same issue running the application in cluster mode. interestingly the job completes successfully sometimes but it fails also. The behavior is not consistent. The job status remains in ACCEPTED for a while then suddenly goes to FAILED status. Though looking at the logs suggest the program has completed till the very end. @mahendra

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got with

spark-submit

> /home/mahendra/Marvaland/SparkEcho/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --class spark_basic.Test_Local /home/mahendra/IdeaProjects/SparkTraining/target/SparkTraining-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

spark session

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("DataETL")
    .master("local[1]")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

thanks @cricket_007

Comment: but this config wont run in cluster mode? I still get the same error running in cluster mode.

Answer (score -1):

This error may occur if you are submitting the spark job like this:
`spark-submit --class some.path.com.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster some_spark.jar` (with passing master and deploy-mode as argument in CLI) and at the same time having this line: `new SparkContext` in your code.

Either get the context with `val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()` or do not pass the spark-submit master and deploy-mode arguments if want to have `new SparkContext`.